# Launching executable in C++

Tags: c++, exec, posix

I wish to launch an executable by API call, but I am not sure if one is supposed to check for executable bit using posix APIs before hand.  What is best practice in this regard?

Comment: I think you're wandering into opinion here, but my opinion is "If you can't run the file, you'll find out pretty fast, so it's probably not worth checking."

Comment: Right.  Perhaps this is an alley I should not tread, but maybe I'm looking for the definitive 'the bit check simply occurs anyway, dont do it', but I have no confidence in it because my .. lack of file system io experience.. [/kicks rock]

Comment: For what it's worth, between the check and the call, another process could change the file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Posix APIs you'll use to launch a process (e.g. `execve()` and friends) will do any and all required filesystem permissions checks in a context that is atomic and secure (and doing so in user space is neither). Best practice is to simply use the syscalls that are available.

As a side note, you can browse the source code of all kinds of tools that invoke the standard `fork`/`exec` team you're talking about. For example [GNU make](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git). I'm sure there are exceptions somewhere in the wild, but practically speaking I've never seen real software attempt to validate filesystem permissions in user space before calling `exec()`.